# Does Perl's smartmatch work against arrays (or arrayrefs) of mixed strings and compiled regexes?

Tags: perl, smartmatch

I'm hoping to use Perl's smart-matching to do look-ups against an array that contains both strings and compiled regexes:

```
do_something($file) unless ($file ~~ [ @global_excludes, $local_excludes ]);
```

(Both the `@global_excludes` array and the `$local_excludes` array reference can contain a mixture of strings or compiled regexes.)

Is smart-matching in Perl that smart? Currently, when I run the above with v5.10.1 I get:

```
Argument "script.sh" isn't numeric in smart match at test.pl line 422.
Argument "Debug.log" isn't numeric in smart match at test.pl line 422.
Argument "lib.pm" isn't numeric in smart match at test.pl line 422.
...
```

Why does smartmatch think that `$file` is a number?

For now, I'm just doing it manually:

```
do_something($file) unless exclude ($file, [ @global_excludes, $local_excludes ]);
```

where `exclude` looks like this:

```
sub exclude
{
    my ($file, $list) = @_;

    foreach my $lookup (@$list)
    {
        if (is_regexp($lookup))
        {
            return 1 if $file =~ $lookup;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1 if $file eq $lookup;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I'm looking to make the solution more Perly.

Comment: FYI, [as of 5.18.0, smartmatch is experimental](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#The-smartmatch-family-of-features-are-now-experimental): "It is clear that smartmatch is almost certainly either going to change or go away in the future. Relying on its current behavior is not recommended."

Comment: You have `@global_excludes` and `$local_excludes`. The first one is a flat list (I assume), but the second one looks like an array ref. Regardless of if the smartmatch does what you want, it will have trouble going over a non-flat thing. It does dereference your `[ ... ]` automatically, but it will probably get stuck on the arrayref inside. Though this is unproofed speculation.

Comment: yes, it's unproofed :) I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Re "Why does smartmarch think that $file is a number?", There's no way to answer your question since you provided absolutely no information about how `$file` was populated and used.

Comment: Simpler syntax: `sub exclude { my $file = shift; for (@_) { ... } return 0 } exclude($file, @global_excludes, $local_excludes)`

Comment: existing code looks perly enough to me

Comment: @ysth, It's not about making more perly, it's about removing completely useless code. There's no reason to go to the trouble of building an array here.

Comment: @ikegami: I was commenting on the question as a whole, the gist of which is "looking to make solution more perly".  wrt your comment, your code is better (except for switching to $_/@_) *unless* they commonly call exclude with only one array of excludes or exclude takes more parameters than shown here

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this does work.  The problem is that one of your excludes is a number, not a string.  When the right-hand side of a smartmatch is a number, Perl does an `==` numeric comparison.

```
my $s = 'foo';
$s ~~ 2; # means $s == 2, warns "$s isn't numeric"
$s ~~ '2'; # means $s eq '2', no warning
```

If you intend to do a string comparison, make sure your excludes are strings.  If necessary, stringify them first (e.g. `@array = map { ref($_) ? $_ : "$_" } @array`).

Comment: @ikegami, sorry, but you're just wrong there.  `2 ~~ "foo"` does not give a non-numeric warning.  `"foo" ~~ 2` does.  This is because smartmatch is primarily (though not entirely) based on the type of the right-hand argument.  The string in the error message is changing because he's testing multiple values for `$file` in a loop.

Comment: CJM: Explicit Stringyfying did not do the trick for me :( Is that because my perl is v10.5.1 ? Thanks

Comment: @user3299282, it's probably in a nested arrayref.  The example code I gave for stringifying doesn't handle recursion.  Try dumping `[ @global_excludes, $local_excludes ]` with [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) or [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Bug found! Was a simple empty string in one of the elements of

```
[ @global_excludes, $local_excludes ]
```

I guess in such case perl 5.10.1 figures an empty string for a number